# How can I change the colors of my bars according to a condition in a ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

```
df <-data.frame(BA_5287)

question <- df$Type.of.Question 
submission <- df$Students.submitted
score <- df$Score.Correctly

cond <- ifelse(abs(score)>94,'darkgreen',
               ifelse(abs(score)<0.94 & abs(score) >=0.7,'yellow','red'))

graph <- ggplot(data=df,
                aes(x=Question,y=Score))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                  color='blue',
                                                  fill=cond)
graph + coord_flip()
```

This is my code. The colors of the bars change but not according to the condition. Can somebody help me please?
Thank you!

Comment: Try to place your `fill` argument into the `aes`: `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Question,y=Score, fill = cond))`. If this is not working, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: you can then use `scale_fill_identity` to get the color you set in this column

Answer (score 2):

The primary problem is that you must use another `aes()` in the `geom_bar` line and call the `fill` argument in that. Then, as @dc37 mentioned above, you just need to use `scale_fill_identity`.

Another thing to note is that you do not need to define the variables outside of your dataframe as you do in your question. You can simply call them by their column names.

Here's an example, with some made up data

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(question  = LETTERS[1:15],
                 score = rnorm(15, 90,5))
```

Rather than a nested ifelse statement, using `case_when` is much more human readable.

```
  df <- df %>%
  mutate(cond = case_when(
    score > 94 ~ 'darkgreen',
    score < 0.7 ~ 'red',
    TRUE ~ 'yellow'   #anything that does not meet the criteria above
  ))
```

Then you can use fill within the `aes()` call to `geom_bar` and add `scale_fill_identity`

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = question, y =score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = 'blue', aes(fill = cond)) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept the answer if it is working for you

Comment: Hello! Sorry for being late for the discussion. Why we do need to insert the `scale_fill_identity()` argument to this code work?

Comment: We use `scale_fill_identity()` because we're supplying the color name directly in the dataframe by making the `cond` column color names, which was what the OP was asking for. If I was doing this myself, I'd probably just use `scale_fill_manual` and provide the breaks directly to the call, rather than creating a vector of color names separately. But they both have the same result